Count the value of the current stock in excel
I'm trying to get the current value of my inventory.
I know the amount of inventory and I have a table that contains all the purchase orders.
So I'd like to start from the last purchase order, get the value and the amount of that order and, if it's not the total inventory yet, continue with the previouos purchase order.
So let's say that I have 7 items of product A in my inventory. I have 3 purchase orders for product A:



PO
Product
Items
Value




PO1
ProdA
3
€15


PO2
ProdA
2
€16


PO3
ProdB
3
€18


PO4
ProdA
4
€16,5



So the current inventory value is for Product A: (4 x 16,5)+(2 x 16)+(1 x 15)
I tried using INDEX and VLOOKUP, but I can't get it to stop at the specific inventory amount.
I'm using Excel 365

Something like =SUMPRODUCT((B2:B5="ProdA")*C2:C5*D2:D5)?

@DarrenBartrup-Cook, that's not entirely what OP seems to look for. Looks like he needs to go from latest Purchase Order (PO4) and count back untill he hits 7 items. Hence the 416,5 + 216 and only 115 (not 315).

@JvdV I wasn't sure so didn't add it as an answer, but yes..... now I've had a proper look and added stuff up... can see the OP says 7 items in inventory while 9 are showing in the table.

Another solution:
=LET(Product,F2,
 inventory,G2,
 Products,B2:B5,
 items,FILTER(C2:C5,Products=Product),
 values,FILTER(D2:D5,Products=Product),
 rows,ROWS(items),
 onHand,REDUCE(inventory,SEQUENCE(rows-1,1,rows,-1),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(MAX(0,TAKE(a,1)-INDEX(items,c)),a))),
 SUMPRODUCT(values,IF(onHand>=items,items,onHand)))



Edit
Have to treat case where there is only one product item as a special case:
=LET(Product,F2,
 inventory,G2,
 Products,B2:B5,
 items,FILTER(C2:C5,Products=Product),
 values,FILTER(D2:D5,Products=Product),
 rows,ROWS(items),
 onHand,IF(rows=1,inventory,REDUCE(inventory,SEQUENCE(rows-1,1,rows,-1),LAMBDA(a,c,VSTACK(MAX(0,TAKE(a,1)-INDEX(items,c)),a)))),
 SUMPRODUCT(values,IF(onHand>=items,items,onHand)))

Notes
Hopefully the filters are self-explanatory.
For ProdA, three rows will be left. Now we need to process the items for those three rows in reverse order to see how much inventory is left at each stage. I've chosen to use Reduce and set up a counter which counts backwards from the last row (Reduce is able to create an array in each iteration, unlike other lambda helper functions). The array produced by Reduce starts with a single value, 7, and goes on to make a stack of the remaining amounts after each transaction. Sequence produces only two values, 3 and 2. Inside the lambda, the functions take the third item, 4, away from 7, leaving 3, and add it to the stack. Next time it takes the second item, 2, away from 3, leaving only 1, and adds that to the stack. Max(0..) stops the results going negative.
In the Sumproduct, the items in the stack stored in 'onHand' are multiplied by their respective values to get the total.

Your solution looks good, but did you check it for ProdB?

Well spotted, you would get a sequence of zero rows in that case so it would fail.

Preliminary solution is:

[H2] =LET(ar,SORT(FILTER(A2:D5,B2:B5=F2),1,-1),ci,G2,
  ai,TAKE(VSTACK(ci,SCAN(ci,INDEX(ar,0,3),LAMBDA(a,i,IF(a>=i,a-i,0)))),ROWS(ar)),
  am,MAP(INDEX(ar,0,3),ai,LAMBDA(x,y,MIN(x,y))),
  SUMPRODUCT(am,INDEX(ar,0,4))
)

Inputs are in the first line:

A2:D5 - the whole data range
B2:B5 - the Product column
F2 - the selected product
G2 - the available quantity of (3).

Update
Improved formula with a single cycle and no FILTER:
=LET(ar,C2:C5*(B2:B5=F2),r,ROWS(ar),
  DROP(REDUCE(VSTACK(G2,0),SEQUENCE(r,,r,-1),
    LAMBDA(a,i,LET(m,MIN(INDEX(ar,i),INDEX(a,1)),
      VSTACK(INDEX(a,1)-m,m,INDEX(a,2)+INDEX(D2:D5,i)*m)))),1))


With tables defines as shown in the screenshot, enter the following in the first cell of column Current Value in tbInventory:
=LET(
    cur_value_for_prod, LAMBDA(prod, num_in_stock,
        LET(
            rev_indices, SORT(FILTER(SEQUENCE(ROWS(tbPO)), tbPO[Product] = prod), , -1),
            instock_and_value, REDUCE(
                HSTACK(num_in_stock, 0),
                rev_indices,
                LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                    LET(
                        in_stock, INDEX(acc, 1, 1),
                        value, INDEX(acc, 1, 2),
                        items_from_po, MIN(in_stock, INDEX(tbPO[Items], cur)),
                        bal_stock, IF(in_stock > 0, in_stock - items_from_po, 0),
                        HSTACK(bal_stock, value + items_from_po * INDEX(tbPO[Value], cur))
                    )
                )
            ),
            INDEX(instock_and_value, 1, 2)
        )
    ),
    cur_value_for_prod(@[Product], @[Inventory])
)


